# What does this 多い do?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011231671000/k10011231671000.html

The sentence in question:
来年は、今年より約１９％多い２万８２００ｔのクロマグロを取ってもいいことが決まりました。

First, my attempt at translation:
"Concerning the next year, it was decided that fishing about 19% from this years..."

I didn't finish the sentence because when I include this 多い into my translation, it becomes gibberish. Judging from the context, I would say that this sentence tells us that it was decided that fishing about 19% of this years amount of fished pacific bluefin tuna would be okay. This years amount of fished p.b.t was ２万８２００ｔ or  28200 tonnes. However, I'm also guessing a bit at this point because I just don't know what function this 多い fulfills here and wether it means something like "amount" here instead of "many".

Comment: I didn't know this either, but Googling around, it looks like "%多い" is used to mean "percent more." I'm sure someone can elaborate, but I think it's just "It has been decided that next year's bluefin catch limit will be 28,200 tonnes, up 19% from last year."

Comment: "from this year", rather.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, 来年　は 今年より...多い implies　"Next year, the fishery amount of bluefin tuna is guaranteed as  28200 tonnes which is more than this year by approx 19%." or using the comment above "...which is up by approx 19% from this year." or like the other answer "...which is up by approx 119% as many as this year.".

As for "A より B は ...　多い/少ない" or "Bは Aより ... 多い/少ない", "より... 多い/少ない" implies "more...than" or "less/fewer...than" in English comparative. "A より Bは" or "Bは Aより"　implies B is the subject in comparison to A.